# Rails 3 + Devise: Set a datetime on user sign up

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I have an attribute for my users called :last_request_at, :null => false

I need to set this attribute to the current time on sign up / create. But I don't know how?

a hidden field in the sign up form maybe? If yes how would that look like? Or how does Devise set his trackable attributes on signup/create to the current time?

**EDIT**

I put this in the user model:

```
before_save :set_last_request

def set_last_request
  self.update_attribute(:last_request_at, Time.now)
end
```

but then I get:

```
stack level too deep
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would set the attribute in your controller action. Your stack level too deep error is because `update_attribute` calls `save` at the end. You are infinitely calling `set_last_request`.

I would just call `@record.last_request_at = Time.now` in your controller action, or modify your before_save hook to just do `self.last_request_at = Time.now`.

Comment: Then I get undefined method `before_save' for 2012-06-18 18:51:29 +0200:Time

Comment: or what do you mean by modifying the before_save hook?

Comment: I meant change your method called by before_save to do `self.last_request_at = Time.now` instead of the `update_attribute` call.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the [`Trackable`](http://rubydoc.info/github/plataformatec/devise/master/Devise/Models/Trackable) module:

> tracks sign in count, timestamps and IP address.

Comment: I know this module... but I specificially need to set my attribute :last_request_at, because it's important for another functionality

Comment: The trackable module saves the user record so you could simply set `last_request_at = current_sign_in_at` in the user's `before_save` hook. Otherwise you could register your own [warden hook](https://github.com/hassox/warden/wiki/callbacks).